# Monkey patch data in dictionary

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

The chart data is stored in a nested dictionary struct `@line_charts`, and I need to convert the prices to target currency with the function `exchange_datasets_currency`. It should finally return the @chart in the end of method.

Is there any way to improve my pattern?

```
def sample_a
    @line_charts = [get_line_chart(@from, @to, "flight_date", "price", tixs)]
    exchange_datasets_currency(@line_charts.first[:datasets], @flights.first)
    @line_charts
end

def sample_b
    @line_chart = _build_line_chart(@from, @to, union_keys, datasets)
    exchange_datasets_currency(@line_chart[:datasets], @flight)
    @line_chart
end

  def exchange_datasets_currency(datasets, flight)
    datasets.each do |item|
      item[:data] = item[:data].collect do |price|
        if price.nil?
          nil
        else
          country = LocationUtils.instance.get_country(flight.from)
          from_currency = LocationUtils.instance.get_currency(country)
          Money.new(price,from_currency).exchange_to("TWD").cents
        end
      end
    end
  end
```